# Store all currently opened excel workbooks and open it later

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently facing a problem in which I want to:

1.Store all currently opened excel workbooks in a an array

2.Save and close the workbook

3.Open back all opened workbooks

4.Focus back to a specific workbook

The current code i have:

```
For Each wb In Application.Workbooks

wb.Save

Next wb
```

Works as expected but my different excel workbooks keeps 'flashing' which is kind of irritating, thus the need to save and close all.

I do understand that to focus back to a specific workbook u can use activate function. If i do an set array inside the 'For each loop', it will not work as it will become a double for loop.

As i'm new to VBA, i would really appreciate any input from you all.

Thank you!

Comment: If i understand your question correctly you are looking for [excel workspace](http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/workspace.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've given you two different options in this code.  Either using a collection or an array.
You can step through a collection using For Each *item* in *Collection* loop while the array would need a For..Next loop.

```
Sub All_OpenWorkBooks_Collection()

    Dim wrkBk As Workbook

    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    'Add to a collection                                 '
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    Dim vItem As Variant
    Dim colWorkBooks As Collection
    Set colWorkBooks = New Collection

    For Each wrkBk In Workbooks
        If wrkBk.Name <> ThisWorkbook.Name Then
            colWorkBooks.Add wrkBk.FullName
            wrkBk.Close SaveChanges:=True
        End If
    Next wrkBk
    Set wrkBk = Nothing

    For Each vItem In colWorkBooks
        Workbooks.Open (vItem)
    Next vItem

    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    'Set a reference to a specific workbook - can then use wrkBk to refer to it. '
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    Set wrkBk = Workbooks("Copy (4) of New Microsoft Excel Worksheet.xlsx")
    wrkBk.Activate

End Sub

    '------------------------------------------------------------------------

Sub All_OpenWorkbooks_Array()

    Dim wrkBk As Workbook

    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    'Add to an array.                                      '
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    Dim x As Long
    Dim arrWrkBk() As Variant
    ReDim arrWrkBk(1 To Workbooks.Count)

    For x = Workbooks.Count To 1 Step -1
        If Workbooks(x).Name <> ThisWorkbook.Name Then
            arrWrkBk(x) = Workbooks(x).FullName
            Workbooks(x).Close SaveChanges:=True
        End If
    Next x

    For x = 1 To UBound(arrWrkBk)
        If arrWrkBk(x) <> "" Then
            Workbooks.Open (arrWrkBk(x))
        End If
    Next x
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    'Set a reference to a specific workbook - can then use wrkBk to refer to it. '
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    Set wrkBk = Workbooks("Copy (4) of New Microsoft Excel Worksheet.xlsx")
    wrkBk.Activate

End Sub
```

Edit:  Note I step backwards through the array loop - as it's counting open workbooks and closing them the number of open workbooks goes down as the loop progresses (so when it got to loop number 4 there's a good chance that workbook number 4 has already been closed).

Edit 2: The comment on workspaces may be just what you're after - I'd check that out first.

Comment: Hi Darren , Thanks for the input! I learnt something new today. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Would adding
    .ScreenUpdating = False 
before your loop help?

And
    .ScreenUpdating = true
after to switch it back on.